# Why is "tyrannis" in "sic semper tyrannis" interpreted as "to tyrants"?

Tags: declension, third-declension

According to the declension in Wiktionary, *tyrannis* is a nominative or vocative **singular** form of *tyrannis*.

So, I can see a literal translation "Thus always, Tyrant!" using the vocative.

But "to tyrants" implies the dative or genitive plural to me, *tyrannidibus* or *tyrannidum*.

(This saying is a paraphrased translation into Latin of a quote from the Iliad, done in Colonial Virginia, used as the motto of Virginia and famously cried by John Wilkes Booth inside Ford's Theater right after he shot Lincoln in 1865.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not *tyrann**ĭ**s*, a form of [*tyrannis* "tyranny"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyrannis#Latin), but *tyrann**ī**s*, a form of [*tyrannus* "tyrant"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tyrannus#Latin).

Without the macron, it could also be read as "thus always, o tyranny", but that doesn't make as much sense as "thus always to tyrants" (i.e. "this is what always happens to tyrants").

Comment: In a more meaningful way, without the macron it could also be ‘tyranny is always thus’ (_sic [est] semper tyrannĭs_), with a nominative rather than vocative.